# Functions inside loop, or loops inside functions

Tags: c, function, optimization

Simply put, which of the following is likely to be a better choice:

```
somestruct data[lots];
for(int i=0;i<lots;i++) {
    a(&data[i]);
    b(&data[i]);
    c(&data[i]);
}
//....
void a(somestruct* d) { ..stuff with d.. }
void b(somestruct* d) { ..stuff with d.. }
void c(somestruct* d) { ..stuff with d.. }
```

OR

```
somestruct data[lots];
a(lots,data);
b(lots,data);
c(lots,data);
//...
void a(int n, somestruct* d) {
    for(int i<n;i++) {
        ..stuff with d[i]..
} }
void b(int n, somestruct* d) {
    for(int i<n;i++) {
        ..stuff with d[i]..
} }
void c(int n, somestruct* d) {
    for(int i<n;i++) {
        ..stuff with d[i]..
} }
```

My understanding would be that for A, the currently active structure will be cached, giving an improvement, but there will be a whole bunch of function calls (a negative).  For B, on the other hand, I will trash my cache, but have 3 function calls, rather than 3*lots function calls.

If my compiler decides to inline a, b, and c, then the first option should be the best choice (as we now have the best of both worlds), however my feeling is that in most cases if it did not, the cost of a function call is far higher than the memory access.

I am aware that the only way to know is to benchmark my specific application, but was curious if there were any rules of thumb that I was missing here.  The first version produces somewhat cleaner code for my specific case, but there is little difference.

### EDIT

I was trying to ask a question about how the cost of entering a function (allocating a stack pointer and whatever else) compares to the cost of a cache miss.  I assume that a generic answer could be useful to other people as well.  However, it seems that the general form of the question cannot be satisfactorily  answered, so here are the full stats, assuming I counted correctly:

- data is 100,000 structs, each containing six doubles and an int.
- a() is six double-reads, three double multiplications, three double adds, and three double stores.
- b() is three double reads, three double multiplies, a four adds, two double compares, and conditionally a call to c.
- c() is three double multiplies, three function calls, and three double writes.

Comment: You're just guessing. And we can't do anything more, as we don't know what the heck those functions are doing, how much data you have, what else is going on in your code, and so on. Benchmark it or stop wasting your own time. That said, my guess is that there's no worthwhile improvement.

Comment: @delnan: I was basically asking "how does a single function call compare to a single cache miss".  Outside of that, the load should be identical.  I am basically just wondering if there is a compelling reason to choose one form over the other. E: your edit seems to indicate "no real difference", cool.

Comment: Not knowing any more than what you have there regarding how the data relates, the single-loop case appeals to me because it reflects the relationship between the three different cases more (all being associated by the need for the loop).

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted I'm fairly certain I know quite a bit about compiler optimizatin and cache effects. And my experience is that it's very hard to even reliably measure a difference from a single cache-conscious change and similar micro optimizations. By the way, the usual inlining heuristics (except the trivial "just inline stuff with `__always_inline`) depend almost entirely on the contents of the function, so the functions being opaque does matter. I love reading about performance, but I also know that this sort of optimization attempt rarely leads to actual improvements.

Comment: The code looks like these functions `a`, `b` and `c` are recursive, so inlining cannot help much (if at all).

Comment: @anatolyg: Apologies, they are not.  I was trying to indicate "some arbitrary computation using the structure".

Comment: @zebediah49 I am risking sounding too opinionated, but my experience is that compilers are very good at inlining, so maybe you should ignore the cost of function-call: it can be significant only if functions are small, and then they are inlined, so the cost is 0

Comment: If the compiler cannot inline the function you can force it by replacing the function with a `#define a(n,d) do{...}while(0)` macro, but I would just try the inline keyword 1st and or compile with -finline (or -O3) or -finline-small-functions if size is more important.

Comment: I'm guessing that the difference in performance is insignificant/indeterminable, especially when "real world" paging/caching performance is taken into account.  More important is which scheme leads to clearer, more robust, more maintainable code, and that depends on a lot more than what you discuss here.  (Can you say "premature optimization"?)

Comment: Your question is quite parallel to the question of [array of structs vs struct of arrays](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-case-study-comparing-aos-arrays-of-structures-and-soa-structures-of-arrays-data-layouts). Maybe you can find clues from that discussion for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main question that you should ask is what is the difference between a function call and a memory access (especially a cache miss).
If the data structure is big (big enough that the cache can't hold it), there will be some cache misses. In the first case you provided, those cache misses will be repeated 3 times, while in the first case, they would occur just once. Moreover, the functions may access the data structure in a sequence like every 10th element. This will increase the number of cache misses. 
If the data structure is small enough, there will be no cache misses and the function calling overhead will take over (if the compiler doesen't inline them). But, in general, you can't presume the size of the data structure that will be analized, so I'd choose the first solution, keeping the problem general. In some particular situation, the second solution could be better.